# How to format a string in JSON format, so that it is recognised as JSON file

Tags: json

I've following string, how can this be formatted in JSON way. I'm getting warning message in VS as `String is not JSON formatted`. I'm trying to understand if this is possible anyway.

```
{
  "speaker": 0
  "transctips":  hi thank you for calling bright house financial my name is problem can I have
},
{
  "speaker": 1
  "transctips":  yeah hi my name is Richard Caillaux and I have a contract with bright house for a %HESITATION a shield level selector %HESITATION product
},
{
  "speaker": 0
  "transctips":  thank you and %HESITATION Mr Dale please be advised that our systems are currently down today R. I. T. Jim is engage and we already expect and we expect to be fully functional within the next one to two hours is there any general questions that I can answer for you
},
{
  "speaker": 1
  "transctips":  no but I'm calling because I need I have a change of address request I need to change my address
},
{
  "speaker": 0
  "transctips":  okay as much as you wanted to %HESITATION modify it for you today
},
{
  "speaker": 1
  "transctips":  our systems are not I'm I mean it's not really working Sir we cannot pull up an account here %HESITATION okay so you just call us back after office after an hour agent
},
{
  "speaker": 0
  "transctips":  yes I want to first
},
{
  "speaker": 0
  "transctips":  is that what you said you wanted to okay %HESITATION hours okay thank you
},
{
  "speaker": 0
  "transctips":  thank you for
}
```

Comment: The rules for JSON are [spelled out and available](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

Comment: So you are aware that this is not a JSON, and you want to make this a json? or you think this is a json and you want to convert it to something

Comment: 1. need [] before head and after tail. 2. need quotes around values.

Comment: @Lei Around *string* values.

Comment: Also need commas between each key/value pair.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the rules for JSON have enough corner cases that you should always find a library to do it rather than rolling your own.

Comment: just use an existing JSON serialiser instead of rolling your own.

Comment: @MarkRansom Obviously. Was there something in my comment that suggested otherwise? The OP is the one with JSON-that-is-not-JSON. There is no library that I know of that will take a string that is not JSON and will make JSON out of it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I was simply suggesting using a library to create this so-called JSON in the first place, rather than trying to fix this mess piece by piece.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sure, just not sure why you addressed that suggestion to me rather than the OP.

Comment: @HereticMonkey without more context in your original comment it sounded like, if I may paraphrase, "this is simple, do it yourself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an attempt to make the first 3 sections of the posted 'JSON' valid:

```
[{
"speaker": 0,
"transctips": "hi thank you for calling bright house financial my name is problem can I have"
}, {
"speaker": 1,
"transctips": "yeah hi my name is Richard Caillaux and I have a contract with bright house for a % HESITATION a shield level selector % HESITATION product "
}, {
"speaker": 0,
"transctips": "thank you and % HESITATION Mr Dale please be advised that our systems are currently down today R.I.T.Jim is engage and we already expect and we expect to be fully functional within the next one to two hours is there any general questions that I can answer for you"
}]
```

You need to put the whole thing in square brackets [], string values need to be in quotes "", and there needs to be commas between each key/value pair.

How did you get this 'JSON'?

You should probably look at something like NewtonsoftJSON to help you create JSON from a collection of objects.

[JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) is very useful for checking the validity of a string of JSON.

Comment: Thanks you Slugsie

Comment: @Aniruddha [Here's the entire document](https://pastebin.com/Z0YFC6v7).